# Rx.Net: observe asynchronous events indifinitely

Tags: c#, asynchronous, rx.net

I have a helper class that saves text messages to the local file system. This method returns a `Task` object, and is asynchronous by definition.

I want to be able to observe when this method gets called, so I can continuously monitor the size and length of the buffer and make a decision based on that.

I am trying to implement this using the Reactive Extension for .NET. However, I can't come up with a design that allows me to continuously listen to messages being added to the buffer. Below is my current implementation:

```
public IObservable<Unit> Receive(InternalMessage message)
        {
            var observable = FileBuffer.BufferMessage(message.MessageId.ToString(), message, DateTime.UtcNow).ToObservable(); //This returns a Task, which I convert into an Observable
            return observable;
        }
```

Here is how I subscribe to the observable:

```
IObservable<Unit> receiverObservable = batchHandler.Receive(message);
            receiverObservable.Subscribe(
                x => Console.WriteLine("On next"),
                ex => //TODO,
                () => // Completed);
```

I want the subscriber to be called every time the method `Receive` is called. However, AFAIK, once this method is called, the observable completes and the sequence is terminated, so future calls to `Receive` won't be listened to.

Can someone recommend a way to use the Rx.Net libraries to implement this observable pattern that I am looking for, that is, how to keep the sequence open and feed it with results for async methods?

Comment: Why not just create event at FileBuffer which will be invoked every time message is buffered, then subscribe to this event?

Comment: I don't have access to FileBuffer code to change it. I could add an event to the BatchHandler class, but I'd like to see if I can solve the problem with Rx natively, as the tools it provides to manage sequences (and combine) might be helpful to me in the future.

Comment: Well you can add event to BatchHandler and then use Observable.FromEvent to create sequence. Additional benefit is events are easy to understand and use and you can use them as is or generate observable sequence.

Answer (score 1):

`Receive` as you've coded it, returns `IObservable<Unit>`, representing the completion of a single task. You want to subscribe to something that returns `IObservable<IObservable<Unit>>` representing a stream of task-completions.

There are a number of ways to do this, the best of which probably depends on how your class is set up and how you're calling it.

Here's the laziest one:

You declare a class-level variable `subject` that represents a stream of your calls:

```
Subject<IObservable<Unit>> subject = new Subject<IObservable<Unit>>();
subject.Merge().Subscribe(
    x => Console.WriteLine("On next"),
    ex => { },  //TODO
    () => { }   // Completed
);
```

Then when you have a new call, you just add it to the subject.

```
IObservable<Unit> receiverObservable = batchHandler.Receive(message);
subject.OnNext(receiverObservable);
```

The reason this is really lazy is that Rx is functional at its core, which tends to look down on mutable-state variables. `Subjects` are basically mutable state.

The better way to do it is to figure out when/why you're calling `Receive`, and structure that as an observable. Once that's done, you can work off of that:

```
IObservable<Unit> sourceReasonsToCallReceive; // Most likely sourced from event

sourceReasonsToCallReceive.SelectMany(_ => batchHandler.Receive(message))
    .SubScribe(
    x => Console.WriteLine("On next"),
    ex => { },  //TODO
    () => { }   // Completed
);
```

Hope that helps.